# Link worktime from one form to another

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I have a model in which we can choose the opening hours of the institution for each day of the week, from such and such to such and such, for example `Monday 12:00 AM - 11:30 PM`

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\db\Expression;

class WorkHours extends _source_WorkHours
{
    public const WEEK_DAY_MON = 'Mon';
    public const WEEK_DAY_TUE = 'Tue';
    public const WEEK_DAY_WED = 'Wed';
    public const WEEK_DAY_THU = 'Thu';
    public const WEEK_DAY_FRI = 'Fri';
    public const WEEK_DAY_SAT = 'Sat';
    public const WEEK_DAY_SUN = 'Sun';


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors(): array
    {
        return [
            'timestamp' => [
                'class'      => TimestampBehavior::class,
                'attributes' => [
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at'],
                ],
                'value'      => new Expression('NOW()'),
            ],
        ];
    }

    public static function weekDays(): array
    {
        return [
            self::WEEK_DAY_MON => 'Monday',
            self::WEEK_DAY_TUE => 'Tuesday',
            self::WEEK_DAY_WED => 'Wednesday',
            self::WEEK_DAY_THU => 'Thursday',
            self::WEEK_DAY_FRI => 'Friday',
            self::WEEK_DAY_SAT => 'Saturday',
            self::WEEK_DAY_SUN => 'Sunday',
        ];
    }

    public static function getWeekDay(string $val): string
    {
        $ar = self::weekDays();

        return $ar[$val] ?? $val;
    }

    public static function hoursList(): array
    {
        $list = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++) {
            $A = 'AM';
            $n = $i;
            if ($i >= 12) {
                $A = 'PM';
                $n = $i - 12;
            }

            $n = $n < 10 ? '0' . $n : $n;
            $_A = ($i === 12 ? 'AM' : $A);
            $list[$i . '.00'] = $n . '.00 ' . ($i === 0 ? 'PM' : $_A);
            $list[$i . '.30'] = $n . '.30 ' . $A;
        }
        return $list;
    }
}
```

Next, I use this model when creating an institution, and the ability to choose the opening hours there

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Wokr Hours</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">

            <div class="form-group">
                <?php foreach (WorkHours::weekDays() as $weekDay => $day) { ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-2"><?= $weekDay ?></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <?= $form->field(
                            $restaurantWorkHoursForm,
                            RestaurantWorkHoursForm::getAttributeName($weekDay, 'open'),
                            ['template' => '<div class="col-sm-12">{input}</div>']
                        )->dropDownList(WorkHours::hoursList(), ['prompt' => ''])->label(false) ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <?= $form->field(
                            $restaurantWorkHoursForm,
                            RestaurantWorkHoursForm::getAttributeName($weekDay, 'close'),
                            ['template' => '<div class="col-sm-12">{input}</div>']
                        )->dropDownList(WorkHours::hoursList(), ['prompt' => ''])->label(false) ?></div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I also use this model when booking a place in an institution where you can choose the time, but here you can choose any time of the day

```
<a class="btn btn-fourth <?= $restaurantReservationForm->getErrors('time') ? 'btn-error' : '' ?>"
               id="reservation-time" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="icon br-clock"></span> <span class="js-value">
                    <?= $restaurantReservationForm->time
                        ? WorkHours::hoursList()[$restaurantReservationForm->time] : '-- : --' ?>
                </span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-height-fixed" aria-labelledby="reservation-time">
                <?php foreach (WorkHours::hoursList() as $k => $v) { ?>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item <?= $restaurantReservationForm->time === $k ? 'active' : ''
                        ?>" href="#" data-value="<?= $k ?>"><?= $v ?></a></li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
```

Now what is the question. I have two forms. In one, the time was indicated, in the other there should be a choice of time from the first form. How can you link the opening hours of the establishment that we indicated with the choice of the time of booking?

Let's say we have a working time `12:00 AM - 11:30 PM`, any time is available in the booking, but it is necessary that there is a choice only within the opening hours of the institution that we specified earlier, that is, from `12:00 AM` to `11:30 PM`, and so on every day, if the time is not selected in the institution for some day , then the booking will also be empty

Is there a way to do this via `json` ?

Comment: You need to store opening hours in session or cookies. This may help https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-sessions-cookies

Comment: @onkarruikar but in the same place this data will not be stored indefinitely

Comment: @onkarruikar can I just somehow link it and transfer the data for the select through json?

Comment: You're not supposed to completely modify questions and titles. If you have another one, please **Ask a New Question** instead of **overriding** a previous one with completely different requirements.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I just wanted to increase the reward, and I did the same question only with a higher price, now I get 2 identical questions, if one of them needs to be closed, then close this one

Comment: @ch11 I'm not sure to understand. **"Link worktime" in PHP** (and the already provided comments) have nothing to do with **"Add track skip button" in JS/HTML/CSS**. Delete your own question (since it currently has no answers) if you want it erased. Ask a new one if you have a completely different one.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I can't delete a question where there is a bounty

Comment: @ch11 Yes, sorry, I missed it's bountied. Well, your other question has a bounty too already. Stick to the plan for now. I'll review your questions and try to give an answer a bit later to give you some help.

Answer (score 0):

This is solvable of course, but you will need to handle it both on the server-side and client-side. The need on the server-side is that you ensure that there is no shenanigans done by a technically advanced user and on the client-side your need is to help the user know from which period he or she can choose the value.

On the server-side you have several choices in terms of storage, but a feasible approach (assuming that the chosen interval will be reused in the future as well) is to store this value into the database. That would mean that you will need a CRUD for this value on server-side and an API function that serves client-side requests, telling the user what his/her choice was. On the server-side you can encode stuff into JSON via `json_encode` and send the result to the client.

You will need a validator both on the server-side and the client-side in order to determine whether a given date is inside the specified interval.

In short, you need:

- Database schema support for this interval
- Application server-side CRUD
- Server-side API
- Client-side functionality that handles the API request
- Validator both on server and client-side
- Handling the logic on the UI rendering and handling using the validator
- Handling the logic when the chosen date or date interval is being stored

Comment: I have all this, I have CRUD, I have a database, I save data in the format `Monday 12:00 AM - 11:30 PM`, I need help with how to use `json_encode`, how in my case to choose the booking date from the one that is in the database

Comment: I have the first form saves this data in the database for the selected institution, the second is the booking form, in which there should be a time selection from the first form

Comment: @ch11 If it is saved in the format that you have specified in your first comment here, then your data model is difficult to use. How do you know which date this interval represents? Or is it a time interval each day? You can separate the parts as `json_encode(explode(' - ', Monday 12:00 AM - 11:30 PM));`, but this kind of raw data handling is probably not what you want. So, what is your input and what JSON would you like to see as a result?

Comment: There is a separate interval for each day, I want everything to be transmitted this way, one for Monday, another for Tuesday, etc., if some day is not filled in the database, then nothing is transmitted at all, let the select be empty there. Something like this

Comment: @ch11 you will need then to store the date as well to which you are to store the interval. Is it already stored?